# Determination of chloride content in aluminium chloride by titration

Tags: analytical-chemistry, titration

TLDR: Is there an as simple and direct as possible method to measure chloride content by titration?

I want to measure the content (mass fraction) of chloride in $\mathrm{AlCl_3}$ powder by titration. Purpose is to measure the purity of the aluminium chloride. For example assume the measured chloride content is 75 % then that means the $\mathrm{AlCl_3}$ is 94.0 % pure.

When I search for how to determine chloride by titration I get the following three methods, which appear to be more complex than needed: Mohr method, Volhard method, Fajans method. All of which use an indicator and require specific conditions and treatments or reagents. The Volhard method is also a back titration and seems to be the default method for some reason which I could not find.

I found the following procedure, which is basically the Volhard method but with an additional reagents (of which I do not know the purpose) and an additional dilution step.

> 1.) Prepare an flask with stopper with 50 ml water and chill in the freezer to form ice.
>
> 2.) Weigh about 1 g of sample and transfer it in to  the flask along with the paper and put the stopper.
>
> 3.) Allow it to come to room temperature. Add a few drops  of phenolphthalein indicator and titrate with 1N NaOH solution to the end point.
>
> 4.) Dilute the solution to 250 mL. Pipette out 20 mL in to another flask.
>
> 5.) Add 3-4 mL of conc. nitric acid , 50 mL of 0.1 N silver nitrate solution, 2 mL of nitro benzene and a few drops of ferric ammonium sulfate indicator.
>
> 6.) Titrate with 0.1 N ammonium thiocyanate solution to reddish brown end point.

No idea what the nitro benzene is for. And the additional dilution step is certainly unnecessary and lowers precision; could just weight less sample and not dilute. The NaOH step is probably to react HCl (which is formed when $\mathrm{AlCl_3}$ reacts with water and may escape and thus lower the chlorine content) to NaCl; but also not sure about that.

What speaks against just directly titrating the chloride containing sample solution with the 0.1N $\mathrm{AgNO_3}$ solution and detect the end point potentiometric?
Am I missing something? Why would people do a back titration with two solutions needed, instead of just a direct titration?

Comment: You can consult Vogel's Quantitative Analysis. There you will find all titrimetric details for chloride and explanations. Web search will only lead to confusion.

Comment: All your answers to the question are available in Vogel.

Comment: @M.Farooq - What, no love for Skoog and West?

Comment: @ToddMinehardt, I like classical books when it comes to titrimetric and gravimetric methods. Vogel's classical Quantitative Analysis from the 60s was a massive book with >1200 pages, all extensive details such as holding volumetric pipette.

Comment: Here is the textbook for the OP on Internet Archive. https://archive.org/details/textbookofquanti0006voge/page/n7/mode/2up?view=theater

Comment: @M.Farooq  Thank you; I found the fith edition to download here: https://gtu.ge/Agro-Lib/Vogels_TEXTBOOK_OF_QUANTITATIVE_CHEMICAL_ANALYSIS_5th_ed__-_G_H_Jeffery.MsuCity.pdf

Comment: There is also explained why to add nitrobenzene: "It is therefore necessary to remove the silver chloride by filtration. The filtration may be avoided by the addition of a little nitrobenzene"

Comment: However, what I still do not know is what speaks against direct titration with $\ce{AgNO3}$ and potentiometric end point detection.

Because that is the method that is currently implemented in our lab. But I could not find anything similar online.

The problem is that it produces slightly to too low assay values for the $\ce{AlCl3}$. Perhaps because of escaping HCl gas; if really that is the reason than dissolving the $\ce{AlCl3}$ cold and in a closed container should in fact be enough.

Comment: You might be searching very specific words. Search Vogel first (later editions) on Internet Archive first for potentiometric titration of chloride. How do you locate the end-point?

Answer (score 2):

This problem is not as easy as it looks. It starts from the hypothesis that $\ce{AlCl3}$ is not pure in the original flask- The impurity will be supposed not to interfere later on. Only $\ce{H+}$ and $\ce{Cl-}$ will be determined by titration.

Let's suppose that the original sample of substance weighs $m_o$ and contains $n\ce{_o mol AlCl3}$. When dissolved into water, this substance reacts according to :  $$\ce{AlCl3 + 3 H2O <=> 3 H+ + 3 Cl^- + Al(OH)3} \tag{1}$$ So, if the hydrolysis is complete (and it will be during titrating by $\ce{NaOH}$), the total amount of $\ce{H+}$ and $\ce{Cl^-}$ in the solution is $3n_o$. The first titration, with $\ce{NaOH}$, determines the amount $n_1$ = $n\ce{(NaOH)}$ =  $n(\ce{H+})$ = $\ce{n({Cl^-})}$ = $3n_o$ produced by the reaction $(1)$. But, apparently, the result of this titration is not reliable enough. The author of the problem is afraid of some unwanted acidic contamination. So the actual amount $n_2$ of $\ce{H+}$ and of $\ce{Cl-}$ due to ($1$) will be obtained by another way, as will be described now.

The second titration is made to determine the amount $n_2$ of $\ce{Cl-}$ ion in solution. But it cannot be done directly, as, after the first titration by $\ce{NaOH}$, the solution contains $\ce{NaCl}$ and maybe some $\ce{NaOH}$. It is first acidified by adding some drops of $\ce{HNO3}$ to destroy this unwanted  $\ce{NaOH}$ . Then a known excess of $n_3$ mol silver nitrate is added. All the $n_2$ mol $\ce{Cl-}$ ions are precipitated as insoluble $\ce{AgCl}$. $$\ce{Ag^+ + Cl- -> AgCl(s)} \tag{2}$$ The solution contains now an excess of $n_3 - n_2$ mol  $\ce{Ag+}$ ions. Some drops of ferric ions are added (plus nitrobenzene - I don't know why). The excess of $\ce{Ag+}$ ions is titrated by gradually adding a thiocyanate solution. In the beginning, it produces the reaction :
$$\ce{Ag+ + SCN^- -> AgSCN(s)}\tag{3}$$ $\ce{AgSCN}$ is a white insoluble precipitate, which looks like $\ce{AgCl}$.

The end point can be determined with a high degree of precision. Because, when the precipitation reaction (3) is finished, the next drop of thiocyanate reacts with the ferric ions to produce a dark red color, made of the ion $\ce{Fe(SCN)^{2+}}$ which is dark red. So as soon as the last amount of $\ce{AgSCN}$ is precipitated, the solution gets red. And this point can be determined with a high precision.

If $n_4$ mol thiocyanate have been added to get to the final red color, the amount $n_2$ of $\ce{Cl-}$ ions can be determined : $n_2 = n_4 - n_3$. And the original mass of $\ce{AlCl3}$ is equal to $m = \frac{(n_4 - n_3) M(\ce{AlCl3})}{3}$, if $M(\ce{AlCl3})$ is the molar mass of $\ce{AlCl3}$. One should find that $m < m_o$

Comment: Maurice, I think HAlCl4 does not even exist.

Comment: @M. Farooq. You may be right, after all. I know that the chloraluminate ion $\ce{AlCl_4^-}$ does exist. But the existence of $\ce{HAlCl4}$ is not proven. So I will edit and modify my answer.

Comment: @Maurice  Thank you for the explanation. The $\ce{AlCl3}$ is supposed to be pure or almost pure (> 99.5 %) as it is purchased from a supplier, but we have to test the assay of it before using it in a production process.

Now, what I really do not understand is: Why is it not common to directly titrate the chloride (be it in the form of $\ce{[Al(H2O)6Cl3]}$ or $\ce{HCl}$ or $\ce{NaCl}$) with the $\ce{AgNO3}$ solution? Then the used volume of $\ce{AgNO3}$ solution directly corresponds to the amount of chloride. Why the detour via a back titration with thiocyanate?

Comment: @Wolfram. Even if the product is sold $99.5$% by the supplier, you cannot avoid that some part of $\ce{AlCl3}$ has been hydrolyzed in the flask during its storage.